# Транспонирование одномерного массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Как транспонировать одномерный `numpy` массив? Ведь функция `numpy.transpose` транспонирует двумерные массивы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если вы хотите превратить одномерный (`1D`) массив в столбец:

```
In [41]: a = np.arange(5)

In [42]: a
Out[42]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [43]: a[:, None]
Out[43]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])

In [44]: a.reshape(len(a), -1)
Out[44]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Comment: Вот как раз это мне и надо. Большое спасибо!